# Processing minim ERROR:NullPointerException

Tags: java, processing, minim

can anybody help me?
I don't know what happened:(

Heres the relevant part of the code:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioInput microphone; 

void setup() 
{
  size(600, 600);
  minim = new Minim ( this );
  microphone = minim.getLineIn();
}

void draw() 
{
  
  float backgroundCol = microphone.mix.level() * 255 *10;
  float rectSize = microphone.mix.level() * 800.0;
  background(backgroundCol,backgroundCol,backgroundCol);
 
}
```

Heres the relevant part of the error:

```
==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Unable to return a TargetDataLine: unsupported format - PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian

=== Minim Error ===
=== Minim.getLineIn: attempt failed, could not secure an AudioInput.

NullPointerException
```

Please tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @Stultuske looks like it's Java, but my question would be, what library is this?

Comment: @JamesDunn import statements in the class, or code without a class? either it's far from complete, java has made some serious changes or this isn't java

Comment: @Stultuske good point, I should have noticed that.

Comment: @James Dunn
I think the library name is【Minim】，its a contributed library

Comment: Please make this test just in case: before using `microphone` in the `draw` method, check if it's null. The issue may just be that it doesn't find your mic when you set it up.

Comment: If you are using a Mac see if this is applicable to your project: https://discourse.processing.org/t/minim-audioinput-nullpointerexception/3557.  On my Mac system it allowed me to get a value for the microphone; otherwise it was null when I checked it with 'println("microphone = ", microphone);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, all. I found solution:https://github.com/ddf/Minim/issues/75

Comment: Please provide also a brief explanation as your answer might be deleted if consists only of a link, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers